# How can i make a form that generates the rows of a database automatically with a foreach in php using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

Hello I want to make an edit and delete form for my Quiz that I have made in the database. But I don't know how I can display the rows in the database with a `foreach` in PHP so when I add one question it will automatically show up in my form.

I have tried this:

```
<?php 
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            $user = '*******';
            $pass = '*******';

            $dbQuiz    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lab_blendi', $user, $pass);
            $questions = $dbQuiz->prepare('SELECT * FROM Vragen');
            $questions->execute();
            $questionResult = $questions->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $output = array();

            $output['title'] = $questionResult[0]["Title"];

            foreach ($questionResult as $key => $aantal) {
                if ($aantal['QuestionId'] > 0) {
                    //do something here???
                }
            }
        ?>
```

If I didn't tell you something you need to know to help, just ask me.

Comment: do you wanna to generate table rows i.e.  `html table rows`   from database output rows???

Comment: You will have to tell us the names of the columns in the `Vragen` table as a `select *` does not give us any clues

Comment: `foreach(...){ echo "something"; }`

Comment: The Columns are QuestionId, Title and Text

Comment: Abbas i just want to show my rows from my database in some form with a foreach but i dont know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetchAll` will return all the results into an array.

It is then just a case of looping around that array in a standard way to get to all the column data returned.

You dont really need the IF test on `$aantal['QuestionId']` as there must be data if the foreach continues looping.

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $user = '*******';
    $pass = '*******';

    $dbQuiz    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lab_blendi', $user, $pass);
    $questions = $dbQuiz->prepare('SELECT * FROM Vragen');
    $questions->execute();
    $questionResult = $questions->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $output = array();

    $output['title'] = $questionResult[0]["Title"];

    foreach ($questionResult as $key => $aantal) {
        echo $aantal['QuestionId'];
        echo $aantal['Title'];
        echo $aantal['Text'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your view of the database to autoupdate when you add somethign in the database. 
This cannot be done in PHP as PHP is serverside and what you need to do this is [Ajax in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).